# long response time of webservice using ibatis and jaxws

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have a web service using JAX-WS and Ibatis, when analyzed with the New Relic tool can see that the running time is 17 seconds. Seeing the detail of the report shows that the database calls are fast, but what is delaying is this: JAXWSWebAppServlet.service (). Someone has an idea that can be ??

[image]

Thanks x your help.

PD: I would like to know where to locate JAXWSWebAppServlet.service () in my code. Any ideas??

The WS code:

```
@WebService(name = "WS_XXXXXX", portName = "WS_XXXXXSoap12HttpPort")
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class WS_GetPlanUsage {

@WebMethod(operationName = "xxxxxx")
@javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding(parameterStyle =    javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public GetPlanUsageMapBean getPlanUsage(@WebParam(name = "phoneNumber",   partName = "request") String phoneNumber,
@WebParam(name = "initialDate", partName = "request") String initialDate, 
@WebParam(name = "finalDate", partName = "request") String finalDate) {

BReturn oBReturn = null;
GetPlanUsageResponse response = new GetPlanUsageResponse();
GetPlanUsageRequest rq = new GetPlanUsageRequest();

rq.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
rq.setInitialDate(initialDate);
rq.setFinalDate(finalDate);

oBReturn = new GetPlanUsageBL().getPlanUsage(rq);

GetPlanUsageMapBean getPlanUsage =   (GetPlanUsageMapBean)oBReturn.getObject();

return getPlanUsage;
}
```

Comment: What about showing what the method does there? Can you share some code?

Comment: I would like to know where to locate JAXWSWebAppServlet.service () in my code. Any ideas??

Comment: That's the automatically generated Servlet that will handle the requests to your web service. Could you provide any code for your web service call, maybe you're using something else, or maybe you're returning a big result and that time is being consumed trying to create the response?

Comment: Add some code. Thanks